# Angular routing with dynamic tabs

Tags: routes

I'm trying to create an angular application that support dynamic tabs with routing.
I found this great starting point here
https://technology.amis.nl/2019/07/05/dynamic-tabs-with-angular-6-and-ng-bootstrap/

The problem with the above solution is that when a tab is hidden the content component is destroyed.

It is required to have the component hidden, and not destroyed when switching tabs, in order to retain the component state.

Setting the destroyOnHide attribute on the ngb-tabset causes multiple router-outlet to be present, and does not work.

One way to retain the state, and have the top level work as expected was to bypass to remove the router-outlet

```
      <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs ; let index = index" [id]="tab.url">
          <ng-template ngbTabTitle>
              <span>{{tab.name}}</span>
              <span (click)="closeTab(index, $event)">&times;</span>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template ngbTabContent>
              <ng-container *ngIf='tab.url =="/movies"'>
                  <app-movies></app-movies>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf='tab.url && tab.url.startsWith("/songs")'>
                  <app-songs></app-songs>
              </ng-container>
          </ng-template>
      </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
```

This works for the top level tabs, but prevent nested routing from working, eg [routerLink]='/songs/1' won't work.

Attempts to use secondary routing also failed.  Short of manual handling of routers event, I couldn't see a way forward.   Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the question is pretty old, but anyway I faced the same issue.

Nice solution would be to use custom RouteReuseStrategy.

With custom strategy you can detach and then re-attach not needed component without destroying it.